# What should we log into haproxy.log?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, load-balancing, haproxy

I am using haproxy load balancer for my QA and Prod servers, and i realized that the size of haproxy.log its growing really fast (7G till now).

I wonder what exactly haproxy log into this log file, and what is the best practice to have a clean haproxy.log file.

**[ Solution to resolve this issue ]**

- Make sure that you have rsyslog instaled use this command to install it if you don't have it

> sudo apt-get install rsyslog

Ps: you can check this [link](http://nickhumphreyit.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-setup-syslog-server-on-ubuntu.html) to correctly configure your rsyslog file.

- Use logrotate to manage logs file/size
  on this [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/) you can find some example on how to configure your logrotate
- Finally, you have to configure both of them to work properly
  Use this [tutorial](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-log-haproxy-messages-only-once/) to do the last step

But I am still curious on what load balancer cave on HAProxy.log file? and why ?

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include an answer. Questions should always be questions only. Instead, you can provide an answer to your own question, or (even better) edit the accepted answer to include the links as it is essentially what you added here.

Comment: Make sense, i will respect this next time :)

Comment: Please respect it **this time**.

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty much use the  `HTTP Log format` offered by HAProxy.
I would recommend you use `rsyslog` and assign a disk space. Also, you need to use `logrotate` and rotate the file every week and may be delete copies older than a couple of weeks.

This [link](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-log-haproxy-messages-only-once/) has a very good explanation on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks Gooner, your answer make sense and with using both rsyslog and logrotate will make the solution salable. But i am still looking for what the load balancer log exactly in those files.

I will add more details and links to my question basing on your suggestion.